# Garbage value is getting inserted into SQLite Database

Tags: c++, sqlite

[image]Inserting values into database, integer values are getting inserted correctly but string values are replaced by some garbage value.
**Using %s or %q as an placeholder for string.**

```
int sl_no1 = sl_no;
    int ac_no1 = account_no;
    string u_name = name;
    string u_add = address;
    int u_bal = bal;
    cout<<sl_no1<<endl<<ac_no1<<endl<<u_name<<endl<<u_add<<endl<<u_bal;

    /** Create SQL statement */
   //sql = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (SL_NO,ACCOUNT_NO, NMAE, ADDRESS, BALANCE) VALUES (" << sl_no1 <<", '"<< ac_no1 <<",'" << u_name <<", '"<< u_add <<", '" << u_bal << "')";
    sql = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES('%d','%d','%q','%q','%d' )", sl_no1,ac_no1,u_name, u_add, u_bal);

    /** Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I am quite sure it's not possible<sup>1</sup> to pass a `std::string` as a parameter to a [c](/questions/tagged/c) variable argument function, use the [.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method for all your strings.

The sqlite API is a [c](/questions/tagged/c) API, so the functions expect a [c-string](/questions/tagged/c-string) for the `"%s"` specifier, the `std::string` is not the same thing, you can use it's internal data by means of the `.c_str()` methods which is a representation of the `std::string` object that is a valid [c-string](/questions/tagged/c-string).

---

<sup>1</sup>It's strictly speaking clearly possible because you did, but

- It's UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, and the garbage values are just there because the function attempted to dereference the `std::string`, which is why it is undefined behavior.
- The compiler might warn about this, and if you are using *gcc* it's almost sure that it will so you either, ignored the warnings or compiled without warnings ON.

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: After using .c_str() the problem is solved. However the gcc compiler doesn't warn anything.